# Command line Argument c++

Tags: c++

I have a program that requires a command line argument to run properly, but it runs even when no argument is provided. How do I ensure that an argument is provided before it runs?

```
int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
    std::ifstream b(argv[1]);
    Word c;

    c.fillWords(c.getWordsAdress(), &b);
    c.printWord(c.getWordsAdress());
}
```

Comment: Check if the value of `main`'s first parameter `argc > 1`.  But we can probably help better if you show us some code.

Comment: sorry, just started using this site.

Comment: also, is it bad to use variables from a class to use methods in the same class?

Comment: No problem & welcome to SO.  I don't get your last question but it seems unrelated to this one so if you cannot find an answer to it, consider asking a new question.  I think your current question is adequately answered by either of the answers below.  You can accept the one that worked best for you to show the author some appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the argument count like this:

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;

    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Note that there is always at least 1 argc because it's the full path to your exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the argument count and if it is less than 2, that means that no arguments were provided. The argument count will always have at least 1, which contains the name of the program.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    if(argc < 2) {
        cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " -argument";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```